# Reduce time while uploading data from file to mysql using hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

I have a csv file which has approximately 1 million records. each row representing a student object.

In service layer, I'm reading the csv file and changing it in to entity as below:

```
 File file = new File("test.csv");
    try
    {
        String csvFile = "test.csv";
        BufferedReader br = null;
        String line = "";
        String cvsSplitBy = ",";
        try
        {
            br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(csvFile));
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null)
            {
                // use comma as separator
                String[] student = line.split(cvsSplitBy);
                System.out
                    .println("Country [code= " + student[0] + " , name=" + student[1] + "]");
                StudentTable st = new StudentTable();
                st.setEmplyoee(student[0]);
                st.setName(student[1]);
                springbootDao.saveStudent(st);
            }
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally
        {
            if (br != null)
            {
                try
                {
                    br.close();
                }
                catch (IOException e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

for dao layer

```
void saveStudent(StudentTable st)
    {
        getSession();
        session.save(st);
        session.beginTransaction().commit();
    }


private Session getSession()
    {
        if (session == null)
        {
            session = entity.unwrap(SessionFactory.class).openSession();
        }
        return session;
    }
```

When I am trying to save it, it is saving for 1 million time, say save for each row which should be as per the logic.

Clearly that is not a good way. Is there anyway I can optimise it using multiple threads to enhance the speed as clearly single thread will take more time or any method in hibernate I can use to dump the data for faster speed?

more update :

i changed it to

```
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null)
{
// use comma as separator
String[] student = line.split(cvsSplitBy); //java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
StudentTable st = new StudentTable();
st.setEmplyoee(student[0]);
st.setName(student[1]);
stList.add(st);
}
springbootDao.saveStudent(stList);
```

now i am facing outofmemoryerror

Comment: What is lac? You could place all of these operations into the same transaction. Does `getSession` create a new session each time?

Comment: 10 lcs = 1 million sir, get session will give you same session each time, updating question

Comment: cannot you save the records in batches: https://vladmihalcea.com/how-to-batch-insert-and-update-statements-with-hibernate/ ?
Probably is also a good idea to make in asynchronously

Comment: Why do you even use Hibernate for this job. You could use a bulk import provided by your database. What database type are you using?

Comment: i am using mysql and i want to do it via java program

Comment: Also see Hibernate Doc about Batch for more Tuning. The essence is, what @f1sh wrote.  https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#batch

Comment: @teclis  yeah , i have done it using batch of hibernate, will add the answer in while. but i have one more doubt. i want to make it faster, as you can see while reading from file only a single thread is reading it from file and mapping into entity. can we save some time here by multithreading.i want to add more threads to read from file but dont have much knowledge in that area. is it even possible ?

Answer (score 0):

done that in this way:

service layer:

```
String csvFile = "test.csv";
    BufferedReader br = null;
    String line = "";
    String cvsSplitBy = ",";
    try
    {
        List<StudentTable> stList = new ArrayList<StudentTable>();
        br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(csvFile));
        StudentTable st = new StudentTable();
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null)
        {
            // use comma as separator
            String[] student = line.split(cvsSplitBy);
            st.setEmplyoee(student[0]);
            st.setName(student[1]);
            stList.add(st);
        }
        springbootDao.saveStudent(stList);
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally
    {
        if (br != null)
        {
            try
            {
                br.close();
            }
            catch (IOException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
dao layer:




// System.out.println("dao layer" + st);
    getSession();
    Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
    session.doWork(new Work()
    {
        @Override
        public void execute(Connection conn)
            throws SQLException
        {
            PreparedStatement pstmt = null;
            try
            {
                String sqlInsert = "insert into student (name,emplyoee) values (?,?) ";
                pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(sqlInsert);
                int i = 0;
                for (StudentTable name : st)
                {
                    pstmt.setString(1, name.getName());
                    pstmt.setString(2, name.getEmplyoee());
                    pstmt.addBatch();
                    // 20 : JDBC batch size
                    if (i % 200000 == 0)
                    {
                        System.out.println(name.getEmplyoee() + "-------------------");
                        pstmt.executeBatch();
                    }
                    i++;
                }
                pstmt.executeBatch();
            }
            finally
            {
                pstmt.close();
            }
        }
    });
    tx.commit();
    session.close();
    // session.save(st);
    // session.beginTransaction().commit();
```